# Take snapshot when doing Windows 7 boot to .vhd

Tags: windows-7, backup, virtualization, vhd

Here is what I would like to be able to do:

- I would like to run from a .vhd.
- I would like to take snapshots of that .vhd.
- I would like to be able to revert back to any of the saved .vhd
  snapshots.

Here is how I currently do things:
I am running a virtual machine through Virtual PC. Before and after I do something major, e.g. install new software, I make a backup of the .vhd. This way I can easily do backups and revert back to the previous state if necessary.

I would like to utilize the boot to .vhd functionality in Windows 7 to avoid the overhead of running a virtual machine.

Is this possible using Windows 7 boot to .vhd or some other method perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've seen the following, look carefully at the limitations.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744399(WS.10).aspx

more info

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440865(WS.10).aspx

Comment: @smoknheap The "What are the best practices for backing up VHDs?" section of your second link provided the information I think I need. I will give it a try.